# phpMyAdmin is not displaying every record

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hey I have a table with about 25700 records. But phpMyAdmin is only displaying about 24300 records. So if I just browsing throught the table he dont show me the last few records. The crazy thing is, if I do a specific select like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID="25700"
```

he is displaying the single record but when I try to list all records with

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

he is only displaying about 24300 records.

Another crazy fact is: if I wanna do an export with phpmyadmin is is not exporting those records which are only available by the first query.

Does anybody here has any experiance with that?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a usage question of a third party application, here namely phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 16):

Add the line: `$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 2000000;`
in your config.inc.php from your phpMyAdmin directory. It seems this problem occurs only with InnoDB tables. So to obtain the exact number of rows, just make `$cfg['MaxExactCount']` large enough.

Comment: @dopamin90 you should accept the answer if it was useful. Thanks